# Rx ForkJoin Missing

Tags: .net, system.reactive

I just downloaded the stable release of Reactive Extensions for .NET and am looking at the [101 Rx examples](http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/101samples). The parallel execution example uses the `ForkJoin` method. This method is not in the stable release (or the unstable for that matter).

How can I do the same sort of arbitrary parallel execution as ForkJoin did?

**Update**

I downloaded from the Rx site, and it wasn't there. I used NuGet like `Anderson Imes` suggests instead and it was there like expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just pulled down the latest version (1.1.10621) from the [Rx_Experimental-Main](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/Rx_Experimental-Main) package and it's still there in `System.Reactive.Linq`. The name of the static class with the appropriate extension methods is `System.Reactive.Linq.Observable`. Verified in Reflector.

Comment: I downloaded from the reactive extensions site, and it's not there, in either version. I just downloaded from NuGet and it's there.

Comment: @Josh Close: yeah, I think they are keeping the "Experimental" stuff out of the site. NuGet is the way to go. They ought to update the Rx 101 site to reflect that.

Comment: This is now in the Rx_Experimental-Main package

Answer (score 1):

From   [MSDN Forums "New Release: Reactive Extensions v1.0.10425"](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/rx/thread/527002a3-18af-4eda-8e35-760ca0006b98)

> Wes Dyer: Looks like I missed a note.  Use CombineLatest or Zip
>   instead of ForkJoin.